# AppLovin unable to precache resources

Tags: android, applovin

I want to use AppLovin Native Ads in my application. I did these

```
AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(getContext());
AppLovinSdk sdk = AppLovinSdk.getInstance(getContext());
        AppLovinNativeAdService nativeAdService = sdk.getNativeAdService();
        nativeAdService.loadNativeAds(3, new AppLovinNativeAdLoadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNativeAdsLoaded(List<AppLovinNativeAd> list) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    presenter.onApplovinNativeAdsLoaded(list);
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onNativeAdsFailedToLoad(int i) {
                presenter.onApplovinNativeAdsFailedToLoad();
            }
        });
```

However, I get error code `-200` which is UNABLE_TO_PRECACHE_RESOURCES. I added `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to manifest. And I did everything the same as in the official tutorial but I still get this error. What can be the cause?

Comment: are you testing on a real device or simulator?  do you have sufficient space on your device or is it full?  what type of device/OS are you on?  you shouldn't need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE unless you're on Android 18 or lower.

Comment: @josh, It's real device. Yes, it does have enough space. Xiaomi Redmi Note 4x, 7.0 api level.

Comment: are you using any sort of proxy or manipulating the network traffic in any way while testing?  this could be related to a malformed ad response.  also, can you try changing the 3 to a 1 in the loadNativeAds function to see if that has any effect?

Comment: @josh, no, I'm not using any kind of proxy. Also, I tried many values: 3, 1, 10 - all of them give me this error

Comment: have you tried the code on any other devices?  your xiaomi device isn't running stock android so there could be something strange happening.

Comment: @josh, I also tried on Huawei and Samsung devices. No luck

Comment: ok, can you enable verbose logging, https://support-developer.applovin.com/hc/en-us/articles/236114328-How-can-I-expose-verbose-logging-for-the-SDK-, and email it along with a brief description of the issue to support@applovin.com